# $k[x]$ with representation space $\Bbb R$ - does this force $k\subseteq \Bbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I try to think up example objects when I come across their concept, and I just read the definition of a representation of an associative algebra $A$.

So I choose representation space $V=\Bbb R$ and want to consider the associative algebra $k[x]$ in this representation space. Consider this $k$ to be characteristic $0$ for convenience.

Now, I thought to myself I can have the homomorphism:
$$\rho:k[x]\to\text{End}(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$$ $\rho:x^i\mapsto [2^i]$ and sends $\forall a\in k,\quad\rho:a\mapsto [a]$. But then for this $\rho(a)=[a]$, this would only make sense if:

1) $k=\Bbb R$ or $k\subset \Bbb R$ or,

2) in certain cases, such as $\Bbb C=k$, I changed the dimension of the representation space $\Bbb R$ to say $\Bbb R^2.$

Of course the second solution isn't the one I want, since it changes the representation space, which I would like to keep fixed in this experiment.

---

So with respect to $1)$ say I didn't have $k=\Bbb R$ or $k\subset \Bbb R$, and wanted to remedy this. Well $\rho:1\mapsto[1]$ and this should be $k$-linear(I believe), so $k\mapsto k[1]$ means that there is no way to fix this it seems.

> Is conclusion $1)$ thus correct? Is there no way to remedy this otherwise. I.e. If I want to have $k[x]$ (characteristic $0$) with representation space $\Bbb R$, then it must be the case that $k\subset \Bbb R$ or $k=\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be any field. If you have a homomorphism $\rho : k[x]\to\Bbb R$, then $\varrho := \left.\rho\right|_k : k\to\Bbb R$ is also a homomorphism. Then $\varrho : k\to\Bbb R$ is either injective or $0$: $\varrho(1)$ is an idempotent in $\Bbb R$, but the only idempotents are $0$ and $1$. If $\varrho(1) = 0$, then $\varrho$ is the zero map. If $\varrho(1) = 1$, then $k$ must have characteristic $0$. Moreover, $\ker\varrho$ is an ideal of $k$, but this forces $\ker\varrho = (0)$, as the only ideals of $k$ are $(0)$ and $k$ itself. Hence, we obtain via the first isomorphism theorem an isomorphism between $k$ and a subfield of $\Bbb R$. Then it follows that $\rho$ itself is either $0$ or that $k$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $\Bbb R$. So if you were demanding that $1\mapsto 1$, your conclusion was indeed correct. If not, you forgot the possibility that your map might be $0$.

Comment: I was requiring that(in regard to $1\mapsto1$), but very nice to see the argument for when that isn't required. I do have one question though - Why is $\varrho(1)$ an idempotent? This is because $\rho(1)\rho(1)=\rho(1*1)=\rho(1)$?

Comment: That's precisely the reason $\varrho(1) = \rho(1)$ must be an idempotent.

Comment: Isn't it necessarily the identity, not just an idempotent immediately from the fact that $\rho$ is a group homomorphism, and group homomorphisms take identity to identity by implication (not axiomatically)? I.e. ruling out $0$? $\rho(1)\rho(s)=\rho(1s)=\rho(s)$

Comment: $\rho$ is a group homomorphism on the *additive* group of $k$, which means that $0\mapsto 0$. A map of rings $f : R\to S$ is additively a group homomorphism $(R,+)\to (S,+)$, but multiplicatively a monoid homomorphism $(R,\cdot)\to (S,\cdot)$ (note that a ring is not a group under multiplication, only a monoid).